# Object pythagorean is not a member of package com - Scala programming error

Tags: scala, package

I am working through Atomic Scala 2.0, learning Scala. I am trying to create a package myself and trying to use it in my programs. This is the code for creating my package:

```
package com.atomicscala.pythagorean

class RightTriangle {
    def hypotenuse(a:Double, b:Double):Double={
        math.sqrt(a*a + b*b)
    }
    def area(a:Double, b:Double):Double={
        a*b/2
    }
}
```

And this is my program:

```
import com.atomicscala.pythagorean._

object test{
    def main(args:Array[String])={
        val rt = new RightTriangle
        println(rt.hypotenuse(3,4))
    }
}
```

When I try to run my program after compiling the package, I get an error like this:

> error: object pythagorean is not a member of package com.atomicscala

Instead, if I name the package as just `pythogorean`, the code works fine. what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by mentioning the Classpath in the Scala command.

> scala filename -classpath . (If the package is in the current working
>   directory)
>
> scala filename -classpath PackageLocation

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the package spelled correctly:

You have:

`package com.atmoicscala.pythagorean`

probably should be

`package com.atomicscala.pythagorean`

Comment: Im sorry, That is just a typo there. It is spelled correct in the program.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is on the "fsc", fsc will reset when classpath change.
You may reset it explicitly by execute the following

> fsc -reset

then you don't need to include -classpath in your scala command. 
note: I am not sure whether this is a good practice.

Another way is to run the scala command without using the fsc offline compiler

> scala -nc filename